# How do you add several characters to a JavaScript map?

Tags: javascript

I have recently created a text to Morse code translator, which was successful, but I am now trying to reverse it to make a Morse decoder (Morse to text). However, the dots and dashes that are supposed to translate in to a letter (for instance: typing ".-" in the translator, should give "a" as the outcome) is not working, instead it gives me "e" and "t" ("." is Morse for "e", "-" is Morse for "t"). I am assuming that the error occurs due to several characters on the key side

> var map = {"key1":"obj1","key2":"obj2"}

This is the current code I have for the decoder:

```html
<html>
<center><h3>Write Morse code:<br/></h3>
<input id='inp' />
<button id='butt'>Decode</button>
<br><br>Result: <input size="34" type="text" id="out" name="morse" readonly/></center>
<script src='script.js'></script>
<script>var morse = {
 '.-': 'a',
    '-...': 'b',
    '-.-.': 'c',
    '-..': 'd',
    '.': 'e',
    '..-.': 'f',
    '--.': 'g',
    '....': 'h',
    '..': 'i',
    '.---': 'j',
    '-.-': 'k',
    '.-..': 'l',
    '--': 'm',
    '-.': 'n',
    '---': 'o',
    '.--.': 'p',
    '--.-': 'q',
    '.-.': 'r',
    '...': 's',
    '-': 't',
    '..-': 'u',
    '...-': 'v',
    '.--': 'w',
    '-..-': 'x',
    '-.--': 'y',
    '--..': 'z',
    '-----': '0',
    '.----': '1',
    '..---': '2',
    '...--': '3',
    '....-': '4',
    '.....': '5',
    '-....': '6',
    '--...': '7',
    '---..': '8',
    '----.': '9',
    '.--.-': 'à',
    '.--.-': 'å',
    '.-.-': 'ä',
    '----': 'ch',
    '.-..-': 'è',
    '..-..': 'é',
    '---.': 'ö',
    '..--': 'ü',
    '...--..': 'ß',
    '--.--': 'ñ',
    '.-.-.-': '.',
    '--..--': ',',
    '---...': ':',
    '-.-.-.': ';',
    '..--..': '?',
    '-....-': '-',
    '..--.-': '_',
    '-.--.': '(',
    '-.--.-': ')',
    '.----.': '\'',
    '-...-': '=',
    '.-.-.': '+',
    '-..-.': '/',
    '.--.-.': '@'
};

var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var butt = document.getElementById('butt');
var out = document.getElementById('out');
butt.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var conv = inp.value;
    conv = conv.toLowerCase();
    conv = conv.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < conv.length; i++) {
        if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
            break;
        }
        conv[i] = morse[conv[i]];
    }
    window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
    conv = conv.join(' ');
    console.log(conv);
    out.value = conv;
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

**UPDATE**:
To anyone with the same issue, the error was caused by "conv = conv.split('')". To fix it, I was adviced by Niet the Dark Absol and Ali7091 to change it to "conv = conv.split(' ')", adding space between ''.

Comment: Your encoder worked because you split on single characters. But in Morse code multiple characters make up a single letter. You need to `.split()` on the separator (space?)

Comment: i think you must split by space : conv = conv.split(' '); instead of it: conv = conv.split('');

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work now. However, every letter are now spaced apart from each other after translation, for instance if I enter "-- --- .-. ... ." i receive "m o r s e". Any clue on how to change the outcome to "morse" (no space in between letters)? I started using JavaScript only two days ago, so I am pretty green on this field, but again thanks for the help!

Comment: do you have a space sign? if yes, you could change this`conv = conv.join(' ');` to joining without space.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.